# Intermingle Javascript and Razor Code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following Jquery Slider initializer that I want to add a simple comma after the end  of a line that needs to be programatically populated.

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: @Model.Offer.PurchaseLimit, <---problematic comma
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui){
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

The comma gets underlined as a 'syntax error'.  My guess is that Razor is trying to interpret the comma.

I have also tried to create a variable outside the javascript function like this:

```
var PurchaseMax = @Model.Offer.PurchaseLimit; <----problematic semi-colon
```

But the problem just becomes the semi-colon.  What do I do to get this to work?

Comment: It appears that this problem only exists in the IDE.  I ran the page and it appears to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this:

```
max: @(Model.Offer.PurchaseLimit),
```

this way the scope of the razor expression is between `@(` and `)`

Comment: But I still need the comma output as a string.  I have commented above as it appears to work just fine when parsed but the IDE does not like it.